# How to add a non-npm dependency to my package.json?

Tags: git, node.js, github, npm

I'm trying to add a specific revision of node-browser-builtins to my package.json file, but it doesn't seem to like the "commit-ish" revision hash. Looking at [npm's documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html), it seems like most of the options under `URLs as Dependencies` require a username. I don't want to give my username.. because that really doesn't make sense. This shouldn't have to be linked to my user to work.

I tried adding this tarball as a dependency - which works when I use it on the commandline (ie `npm install`):

`https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/tarball/e5f81125f3c37532d7def0736265dbe87861e5e4`

but it gave me this error: `Error: 404 Not Found`. Looks like its adding an `@` on the end of the URL, which will obviously make it fail..

I've also tried option 1 in [the documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html):

`git://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins.git#e5f81125f3c37532d7def0736265dbe87861e5e4`

but it gives me the error:

`npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: ambiguous argument 'e5f81125f3c37532d7def0736265dbe87861e5e4@': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Looks like its erroneously adding an `@` in this case too.

I *have* gotten it to work by doing this:

`git+https://myUserName@github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins.git#e5f81125f3c37532d7def0736265dbe87861e5e4`

But again, I don't want my username associated with the dependency. So how are you supposed to do this?

More info: I'm on windows 7, npm -v 1.2.24, and my package.json has dependencies listed in an array (`[]`), not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---Updated Answer---

For git, I now do it using the archive path:

```
https://github.com/fresheneesz/trimArguments/archive/e69ed3ebdfe6cf055916ba6e3a1e4b28f696da6f.tar.gz
```

---OLD---

I figured out a way to do this, but I still would like answered, my questions about why my previous attempts failed.

The way I got it to work is replacing my username with `git`. So:

`git+https://git@github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins.git#e5f81125f3c37532d7def0736265dbe87861e5e4`

If I need to add a dependency from a tarball though, I still don't know how to do that. So this isn't a complete answer.

Comment: Just for clarification: Based on B T answer, the complete "thing" to add to the package.json in dependencies || devDependencies node would be something like: "my-module-name": "git+http[s]://git@url/to/repository.git#branch". This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple solution for opensource packages:

- Make a package that includes probably just a `package.json` file
- Set the `preinstall`, `install` and optionally `test` hooks [example](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html#EXAMPLES)
- Publish it and put it as a dependency in your package

#### Sample `package.json`

```
{
 "name": "foo",
 "config": {
  "port": "8080"
 },
 "scripts": {
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall" : "wget yourtar && tar -zxvf && cd to/your/folder && ./configure",
    "install" : "make && make install",
    "test" : "make test"
  }
 }
}
```

Please make sure you deploy a decent, cross-platform (or at least cross-nix*) and reusable package by [following the guidelines](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html).